# Generating OpenApi (Swagger) with Swashbuckle in GeneratePolymorphicSchemas mode, how to configure it to use $type prop from JSON.NET?

Tags: asp.net-core, polymorphism, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.NET Core 3 WebApi with polymorphic DTOs. I'm using Json.NET to add `$type` field to my json, i.e. `"$type":"CrazyIvanMotors.DTO.Animal.Dog, CrazyIvanMotors.DTO"`.
I'm trying to generate an OpenApi 3.0.1 schema.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson((config) => 
            {
                config.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
            });


    // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        c.GeneratePolymorphicSchemas();
    });
}
```

Swashbuckle properly detects polymorphic classes and adds `$type` property, but does not put correct constant values into type or generate any `mapping` as described here [OpenApi doc inheritance and polymorphism](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/)

```
      "Animal": {
        "required": [
          "$type"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "$type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "discriminator": {
          "propertyName": "$type"
        }
      },
      "Dog": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Animal"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "sizeCategory": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        ]
      }
```

Am I missing some configuration here?

Comment: yet to find a good explanation on how to do that, spent so much time already...basically now the generated client successfully calls the api and returns some of the properties fine but the base type and its sub types are empty...